# How can i preserve the modification time when copying HDFS file to Local without preserving the permissions?

Tags: unix, hadoop

I want to copy files from HDSF directory to local directory by preserving the time

I've tried `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal -p <HDFS_DIR> <LOCAL_DIR>` But this is trying to preserve the permissions as well which I don't want.

I've tried `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal -pt <HDFS_DIR> <LOCAL_DIR>` That dint work and getting this complaint `-copyToLocal: Illegal option -pt
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -copyToLocal [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>`

Tried with -get as well

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Could be be more clear on the preserve the permission thing a bit. What permissions you want to keep?

Comment: Are you just trying to preserver the modify time, but nothing else?  I don't know what hdfs maintains, but can't you just `chown` the file back to whatever you want once it's copied with `-p`?  Or `chmod`, if that's what you need.  Or, some `touch` implementations let you set the *mtime*.  Important safety tip: do not google "man touch".  I found it doesn't do what you might expect.

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker When we use -p when copying files to local from HDFS it will preserve the permissions and file modified time from HDFS. For example : hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /tmp/test_File.txt /Local/tmp/ when the user and owner of the test_file.txt is X and Y and the modification time is 2017-xx-xx 10:10:00 it will create the same copy in local with the sametime and user, owner. What i want to do is ignore the user and owner and just preserve the time while copying

Comment: @ErikBennett I cannot use chown because I'm using the copyToLocal on a container when running the oozie shell action, the container will not be happy to change the permissions. I cannot use touch in my case either. So basically if we have a parameter something line --ignore-permissions for copyToLocal or get that will help me.